# How to only save new tweets/instagram photos to database?

Tags: php, database, twitter, instagram

I'm building a two cron-jobs that regularly searches new tweets and instagram photos(and potentially more services) based on a tag.

The content is saved to a database and are later outputted to a webpage. This allows for faster loading and more importantly the ability to remove certain tweets so they are not displayed.

I want to make sure that no posts are saved twice in the database and am not sure what approach is best. Here are some options I consider:

- I use Laravel and has the ability to demand the postID to be unique, this would make the database refuse when I try to save already existing posts. This might render unnesseary sql-queries though.
- I could check the database for the latest saved post ID and stop the loop once I get to that post.
- Atleast in twitter, I can pass the parameter since_id, wich allows me to just get the latest posts. However I haven't found the same parameter in instagram and it wouldn't work for html-scraping either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twitter provides the 'created_at' value, giving you a date and time the tweet was created.

Each time your cron job runs, store the date and time, then on the next run, only upload the tweet if the date/time is prior to the value of 'created_at'.

I'm not too familiar with Instagram, sorry - but I assume the same logic would apply.

```
["created_at":"Wed Aug 27 13:08:45 +0000 2008"][1]
```

Comment: Is this better than just preventing the once that are already saved in the database from being saved? Why? Whynot?

Comment: It's better IMO because it's not querying the database at all except to enter valid new tweets

Comment: And why would I want to avoid that?

Comment: For one it takes longer to ask the database to find out if it exists, than it does for PHP to see if the date is prior to the created_at value. so - Reduced Execution time would be one answer to that

Comment: how about 2 feeds with same time? at same secend?

Answer (score 0):

Even though there is no "since_id" parameter in Instagram, you can basically do the same thing.

Get the id of the last post you have in your Database. Sort you array of new Instagram posts by id. You should then be able to easily remove from the array the posts that have an id lower than the last id in your database.

Once this is done, you can save them in your database.

Note that the same thing could be done using timestamps instead of ids.

Comment: Is this better than just preventing the once that are already saved in the database from being saved? Why? Whynot?

Comment: Sorting out the posts you don't want, say, in php, is much more efficient than making unnecessary queries. Queries are heavy. Usually, the less queries, the better.